# ios - Heap growth with ARC on

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory-leaks, abandoned-memory

Discovered a heap growth every time running one method that updates data and UI.
Here is what I see in Inspector:
[image]
There is a huge heap growth about 1MB every time I run the method. After several calls app crashes.

[image]

Going down by the callstack found this static function:
[image]

[image]

Can't find any memory leaks in code. Please help. (ARC is ON)

**UPDATE:**

So now I'm using one NSCalendar object in that static method and it helped some, but there is still **1MB more** every time I run the method. 
[image]
And now Inspector shows many memory addresses, that are not connected with code.

[image]

Comment: Hard to say... that "dateDifferenceFromDate" surely isn't responsible for 1mb of leaks.  Probably something in your code is retaining some of your UI, or you have a retain cycle in your code.  There's not much we can do without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Well - clearly dateDifferenceFromDate is not the culprit. GraphController::drawGraph seems to be the one as its updating UI when you see memory spike. Can you paste more code for drawGraph?

Comment: Ok. Here it is http://pastebin.com/yvvX6GZM big and dirty. But I think most interesting is that i have such property
`@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *drawArea`

and in the end of drawGraph I change it.

Comment: @Goga Don't be afraid to use helper methods. Split that behemoth up. It'll help you and anyone else who looks at that method later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with dateFormatter. It was its container extra retain. For some reason I was calling **setParentView** on controller.

Answer that helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767593/1974008

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create so many `NSCalendars` - If you reuse an `autoupdatingCurrentCalendar`  (e.g. save it into a `GraphController` ivar) and pass that in to `-dateDifferenceFromDate:to:`, you can (virtually) eliminate calendar creation.

**UPDATE**

> Can this help with abandoned memory or it's only improves speed?

The best way to see how much this suggestion helps is to **measure**. Your screenshot suggests ICU timezone (used by calendar) creation as the heaviest part. IDK how many times you call this (i.e. how many `NSCalendars` you create, or if the implementation shares/caches information through this API) when drawing the graph… but the information you present leads me to believe it is 'many' -- and that is one calendar per call to `-dateDifferenceFromDate:to:`.

So yes, it can eliminate (unnecessary) duplicate objects -- `[NSCalendar currentCalendar]` does not return a singleton (your samples demonstrate that).

Also note that `NSDateComponents` may reference the calendar instance.

Creating calendars can be very time consuming (not just memory).

Also note that `NSCalendar` is *not* thread safe.

So your program probably creates a lot of temporaries, unnecessarily. Most (if not all) of the memory will be released 'shortly', but if you've a lot to 'calculate' then you may have huge deposits in your autorelease pools (which eventually get drained). You can create inner autorelease pools to reduce this, but using one calendar is an easy optimization for speed and memory.

Many system APIs cache behind the scenes and result in surprising memory growth, but IDK if this is one of them.

This blog post might also be interesting: http://www.mikeabdullah.net/NSCalendar_currentCalendar.html

But really, I'd just try using a single auto-updating calendar, then measure. Then you will know how much it helps *your* implementation.

Comment: Can this help with abandoned memory or it's only improves speed?

Comment: helped, but seems it's not the main problem. Please, see my update.

Comment: @Goga can't help much with the information provided -- symbolication would help.

Answer (score 0):

The memory "leak" is not the cause of your crash. Clearly the memory is reclaimed by ARC. Can you tell us about the crash?

Comment: Why not? Everything goes fine and super fast, but if I repeat updating (about 5 times) it crashes.